# Is this a disadvantage of using sleep() or a problem with outputting the count every iteration? (Child process doesn't execute as far as expected)

Tags: c

Just a real quick question. Could someone either confirm or correct my theory as to why my child process does not execute as far as I would think? Given what I have, I would expect the child to reach 999 as the parent sleeps for 10 seconds so this would result in 1000 total incrementations of iter. However, it only reaches around 860 on output. My assumption is it has to do with the fact it has to output the count in between every 1/100 second sleep, but I am not convinced. I also considered the manual documentation I found on usleep which said that the function guarentees a delay of **at least** that long. Is it one of those two or a combination of both?

```
int main() {
    int iter=0, forkedProcess;
    forkedProcess = fork();
    if (forkedProcess == 0) {
        while (1) {
            iter++;
            printf("Count for process: child is %d\n", iter);
            /* sleep for 1/100 of a second */
            usleep(10000);
            }
     } 
     else {
         printf("Process sleeping for 10 seconds: Parent\n");
         sleep(10);
         kill(forkedProcess, SIGTERM);
         printf("Process killed: child. Waiting for it...\n");
         wait(NULL);
         print("Everything has finished");
     }
}
```

Comment: Perahaps  `sleep()` and `usleep()` are counting different times: wall vs processor time?

Comment: Hmmm, thats an interesting thought, but I'm not sure if that is the case because I found no reference to sleep() or usleep()'s timekeeping methods being based on anything other than what I would assume is wall time for both

Comment: I then suspect real CPU usage and overhead.  Try `printf("Count for process: child is %d\n", iter); usleep(5000); printf("Count for process: child is %d\n", iter); usleep(5000);`.  Still 860?

Comment: "*it has to output the count in between every 1/100 second sleep*". Yes that is a very possible reason. You can test it by removing the `printf` and using a signal handler to catch the signal so that the child process can print or return the last `iter` value. Note that `printf` should not be called in signal handlers so the handler should just set a variable to tell the main loop to exit and print/return.

Comment: Hmmm, I do believe @kaylum that that would be a good way to test it. The problem is, I am rather new to some of this stuff so I am not quite sure how to implement a signal handler to carry out that task. Currently looking but am somewhat confused

Comment: @Reinstate Monica I did try that as you suggested, however, it did not reach 5000. It fell just short, similar to the current situation

Comment: Haven't got time now but when I do and if there isnt a resolution yet I can try and show how to write the sig handler. A simpler way to prove the point may be to reduce the number of `printf` calls. Say print it every 100 iterations. If you do that do you get closer to the expected total?

Comment: Thank you. Yeah, when I printed it out by 100's and then let it print every value over 990, it was able to reach 993, so I think it must be the printf function. That said, I would greatly appreciate a demonstration on how to write the sig handler when you have the time.

Comment: Interestingly, I must add, it doesn't seem to get above 993 when I get rid of the printf for every 100 and just let it print every value above 990

Comment: Since `usleep()` delays _at least_ the given time, it could also delay longer, giving you less loops. On what OS are you trying this? Commons desktop systems are no real-time systems. Many things can delay processes at any time. I had several bad experiences on Windows that delayed my processes for multiple seconds.

Comment: I think that plays a role in it asweel @the busybee. Getting rid of the printf got me closer, but i assume there is also some drift from usleep. I am running this on a virtual linux desktop